# Does Wicket has inbuilt Local Storage support

Tags: wicket, local-storage

we can use local storage from javascript

but does wicket provide any class which helps in local storage?

in GWT we can directly write

```
Storage.getLocalStorageIfSupported().setItem("user", result.getUserName());
```

so does wicket provide anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

Wicket doesn't come with this out of the box. It would be some work to add such support from the server side of things: Wicket is primarily a server side framework. Probably you can attach local storage events to `AjaxRequestTarget` using the `appendJavaScript` method.

Perhaps one of the 1000 projects at https://github.com/wicketstuff/core provides one implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. it means we have to do it via JavaScript itself.